# Cursor is huge on Ubuntu due to high resolution monitor

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, cursor

So I have a 4k display, and for some reason Ubuntu decides that it's a good idea to give me a huge cursor instead of something normal. I don't have any DPI settings on the 4k monitor, and I don't want any, so why is the cursor so huge? This is how it looks like:

[image]

This is on Ubuntu 15.04 with XFCE4 with Nvidia drivers.

It only looks like that when the mouse is over system-dependant things (or something in that nature), such as the desktop, window titles, menu bar (File, Edit, View, ...) and context menus.

In Firefox it seems to work just fine, except in the bookmarks dropdown.

What I've already tried:

- Running `update-alternatives` to force the cursor theme. This changes the cursor theme, but it doesn't change the cursor size.
- Modify the cursor size in `dconf-editor`. This doesn't do anything.
- Put `Xcursor.size: 24` in `~/.Xdefaults`. This also doesn't appear to do anything.

`xrdb -query` returns the following:

```
*customization: -color
Xft.dpi:    96
Xft.hintstyle:  hintnone
Xft.rgba:   none
Xcursor.theme:  DMZ-Black
Xcursor.size:   24
Xcursor.theme_core: 1
```

Comment: Did you try changing the theme and/or the `pointer` setting in the theme?

Comment: Yes, the pointer size as shown by `dconf-editor` is 24, which is the default. I can change the cursor theme to something else, but the size remains the same.

Comment: I've also tried setting the pointer size to 16, there is no change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up solving it myself (kind of). It's not the ultimate way, but it's a workaround that I can live with myself.

Essentially, I took the original sources of the DMZ-Cursors package and created a fork of DMZ-Black, then I removed the `32x32` and `42x42` images, and am now using that as my cursor set.

For convenience sake, I've put up my version of DMZ-Black on Github: https://github.com/codecat/dmzblack-96dpi

If you wish to do the same with DMZ-White, simply download the sources [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/dmz-cursor-theme_0.4.3.tar.gz), copy DMZ-White, and remove all lines mentioning `32x32` and `42x42` in the `*.in` files. You can also remove the folders for those images if you want. Then simply run `make.sh` and copy the generated cursor files (in `../xcursors`) to your cursors folder. (You can take [my install script](https://github.com/AngeloG/dmzblack-96dpi/blob/master/install.sh) and [change_cursor.sh](https://github.com/AngeloG/dmzblack-96dpi/blob/master/change_cursor.sh) as an example.)

Comment: I just joined this site so I could login and up-vote you for this. amazing, ty.

Answer (score 3):

[image: cursor settings]

I was able to fix this in Kubuntu 19.10 by changing from "resolution dependent" to a fixed size in the Cursor settings.

Answer (score 2):

I came up against this same issue, but didn't want to switch to one of the DMZ cursor themes, so I figured out how to apply @Angelo Geels' method to the Oxygen cursor themes:

```
# Ensure that dependencies are installed
sudo apt-get install cmake inkscape

# Download the cursor source
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/oxygencursors/oxygencursors_0.0.2012-06-kde4.8.orig.tar.gz

# Unpack
tar -xvzf oxygencursors_0.0.2012-06-kde4.8.orig.tar.gz
cd oxygencursors-0.0.2012-06-kde4.8.orig

# The critical modification step
sed -i "s/90 180 270/90/" theme-*/CMakeLists.txt

# Prepare the build directory
mkdir build
cd build

# Build the cursors
cmake ..
make # This will take a long time, so use -j<n> or specify a single cursor to build (make theme-<color>)
```

When this process is done, the modified themes will be in `build/packages` to install however you wish (with `lxappearance`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I noticed that if I have the login set to auto, then cursor is big and regardless of all my attempts (I've tried all suggestions posted here) it will not change to regular size. If I have auto login switched off so that I need to enter my password at login, the cursor is of correct size.

Answer (score -1):

Update your cursor theme and cursor size first of all

First in a terminal type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

Choose the number of the theme you want - e.g.

```
0 for DMZ-White
```

Reboot your system.
Using ***dconf-editor* (install using *sudo apt-get install dconf-tools*)** navigate to

```
org.gnome.desktop.interface
```

[image]
change the cursor size to

```
24 and cursor theme to DMZ-White
```

Comment: OP has perhaps already tried this, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I checked it round a bit, and many have reported getting inconsistent results. It may be a bug in the system.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work for me unfortunately. It changes the theme of the cursor after the reboot, but it doesn't change the size.

Comment: After further testing found out that the   **sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme**   command to choose one among cursors with manual mode was sufficient.  Reboot your system after that. Hope this works...

Comment: That changes the cursor theme, yes, but not the cursor size, which remains the same.