# X11 with systemd/user: Mouse pointer size inconsistent

Tags: systemd, xorg

I use xorg as user service follow: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Xorg_as_a_systemd_user_service

I ported all other deamons to user services but there's a point that I can't achieve - a user service named `xresources.service` that I start successfully under userland.

Behavior with start globally:

```
start X via startx util.
mouse pointer size in expected same size when put on firefox/chrome and other 
apps AND on window manager itself without any app.
```

Behavior with start on userland:

```
start X via user service.
mouse pointer size in expected same size when put on firefox/chrome and other 
apps BUT on window manager itself without any app, mouse point size is bigger
than expected.
```

I suspect `xorg` did load something from root userspace and force mouse pointer behavior.

EDIT: `startx` did something that systemd services donot do, if we can know the differences I think we can adjust instead of patching theme or system, I use almost default `.Xresource` just add some color and change the font.

Manually change dpi: `Xft.dpi 200` doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Huge mouse cursor in some windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423633/huge-mouse-cursor-in-some-windows)

Comment: But why with `startx` wrapper I don't have issue? so probably not a dup, and I'd like to not manually patch the system: archlinux.